# Access to private method using reflection in C#/Silverlight applications

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection

My code invokes method using reflection:

```
        scoringType.InvokeMember("scoringClient_ScorePostsCompleted",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, scoringInstance,
            new object[] { sArg, eArg });
```

where scoringInstance is an instance of a ModelView class. The method is private, but I use BindingFlags.NonPublic, so, i should be able to access it, but I cannot - I get MethodAccessException exception: "Attempt by method ... to access method ... failed."
Google doesnt seem to have an answer. Do you have any idea how to fix it by any chance?

Comment: Review the ReflectionPermission class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on silverlight

> In Silverlight, you cannot use reflection to access private types and
>   members. If the access level of a type or member would prevent you
>   from accessing it in statically compiled code, you cannot access it
>   dynamically by using reflection.

Edit:

Silverlight 5 now does allow for reflection of private members ONLY if you're running with elevated privileges either out-of-browser or in-browser (in-browser using the generated test page DOES NOT WORK).

Comment: Thanks! You saved me hours of failed attempts :)

Comment: @MerickOWA, any workaround? any way to trust my apps? `Reflection.Emit`?

Comment: @Shimmy I did some more testing and the only work around is to use Silverlight 5 with elevated privileges either in-browers or out-of-browser.  Silverlight 4 elevated privileges does not allow reflection.  I'll update the answer to reflect this since Silverlight 5 has been released.

Comment: I'm on SL 5. I'll make a research on elevated trusts.

Comment: Just FYI, the ability to get at private members with elevated privileges is buggy on Mac OSX. I've had to work around an issue where code in a leaf class *can* access the private member but the exact same code in the leaf's parent cannot... it is bizarre.

Comment: @MerickOWA. Hi Merick, I am trying to access an internal member on ManualResetEvent class (SafeWaitHandle) but I get FIeldAccessException. I am running SL5 with elevated permissions.  What exactly did you mean by "DOES NOT WORK in-browser using generated test page"? I replaced the webpage with a new one and made that as the startup page but it is till the same. Can you provide more information. Thx

Comment: @user559788 just what it says, it wont work.  You need to associate your silverlight application with a local asp.net website project, and launch the website instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you need access to non-public members, you can do this using the *LambdaExpression*.
I wrote this [article](http://vvson.net/Home/en-US/Article/access-to-non-public-members-in-silverlight) that explains in detail why it works.

Comment: LamdaExpression doesn't work for SL 5 .NET internal methods marked with SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute. Have you tested your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution also does not work for internal methods with `SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute` attribute.