# How to set private fields on a domain model in the repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, domain-driven-design

I am currently working with a codebase that uses the Anaemic Domain Model, and I am trying to move more logic into the domain models in a move towards a Domain Model and Domain Driven Design, but I am struggling with the following problem.

I have a domain model called Job which looks like this,

```
public class Job
{
   private DateTime _someOtherDate;
   private DateTime _lastUpdated;

   // this may be called from many different services
   public void SetLastUpdated()
   {
     _lastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
   }
}
```

At some point in time, during the processing a job I want to set the job's last updated date to that specific point in time. To do this I have created a public setter for it as you can see above.

An issue arises when I am pulling back the Job from the database in my repository, as I now have no public setter for this field because I have restricted that to `SetLastUpdated()`.

Can someone please advise on how I could allow this property to be set in the repository implementation when retrieving the job, but not from the service where it is restricted to calling `SetLastUpdated()`.

**Update 1)** I have updated the question as using start date was a bad example.

**Update 2)** From the answers given, the only way I can see this being done is by not using AutoMapper in the repository, adding a constructor onto the Job class for setting _lastUpdated, and using this when constructing the Job to be returned in the repository's job retrieval method.

Comment: What sort of pattern are you using to hydrate your domain models?  Are you using an ORM, or mementos?  What do your constructors look like?

Comment: I am using AutoMapper to map the Entity Framework models back to the domain models. This is where the start date will be set. There are no constructors on the domain models, they are anaemic by design.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What domain behavior uses the _lastUpdated? If none, push it down to the store level (if possible)?

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, you have various options.

**Option 1**

Assuming that your repository has two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Job> ReadAll() { ... }
public int CreateJob(Job job) { ... }
```

You can give the `Job` class two constructors, one that takes a `DateTime` and one that does not.

```
public class Job
{
    public Job(DateTime startDate)
    {
        this.StartDate = startDate;
    }

    public Job() : this(DateTime.UtcNow)
    {

    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
}
```

This does not prevent the service from calling the "wrong" constructor, but at least it communicates the option of calling it without the `startDate` to the caller.

**Option 2**

Work with two different `Job` classes.

Your repository could look like this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<Job> ReadAll() { ... }
public int CreateJob(NewJob newJob) { ... }
```

And the `NewJob` class could look like:

```
public class NewJob
{
    public NewJob()
    {
        this.StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
}
```

This communicates intent better, because the repository's `Create` method only accepts an instance of `NewJob` so the user of the model will be forced to create a `NewJob` instead of a `Job`.

**Option 3**

Ignore the `StartDate` in the repostory's `Create` method and always set it to `DateTime.UtcNow` within the method. Or even go so far as to create an `Insert` trigger in the database that sets it.

Comment: Thanks for answering Klaus. I think using start date in the example was a bad idea. Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to use constructors for this

```
public class Job
{
   private DateTime _startDate;

   public Job()
   {
     _startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
   }

   public Job(DateTime dt)
   {
     // check DateTime kind, this could be source of a bug
     if(dt.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc) throw new ...
     _startDate = dt;
   }
}
```

You have to expose this method/property one way or another. If repository can set it, you can set it from other locations. If you try to be smart about this (you could, for example by using interfaces), you'd get into a risk of overengineering.

Comment: Hi oleksii, Interesting check using .Kind, thanks for that! I think using start date in the example was a bad idea. Check my update.

Comment: @Jonathan C# DateTime is pain in a butt to work with. You'd see this exception will be firing a lot. We have had a few bugs with this. When ORM (Automapper) creates a new DateTime, by default the kind is unspecified, if I remember correctly. This object will happily accept the utc date, but will "forget" to set the utc kind.

Answer (score 1):

One of the primary reasons you're doing DDD is to take advantage of the managed mutability that can be provided by encapsulation.  That is **always** going to start with the constructor.

In general, this is the type of work an ORM is specifically designed to perform, however it can also take advantage of any existing DTOs that would have been mapped onto the domain object by using the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern):

```
public Job() {
    _lastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    // ...
}

public Job(JobData data) {
    _lastUpdated = data.LastUpdated;
    //...
}
```

re: `AutoMapper` - it's <strike>been a while since I used it, but it should be</strike> [possible for you to instruct it to access fields using reflection in the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911950/is-automapper-supposed-to-work-with-private-setters-oob).

Comment: While you have good points, I don't understand couple of things. First, OP's code doesn't have getter or setter for the date time field. There is only one method to "set it to utc now". So external code cannot see it or set it. Thus "the current code doesn't actually prevent _startDate from being changed at any point in the future" appears to be erroneous. Second, memento pattern is good for restoring state of an object to previous states. I cannot see how it's relevant in this context.

Comment: @oleksii The method signature I was referring to was `public void SetStartDate()`, which the OP has since edited to `public void SetLastUpdated()`, to which my statement is much less applicable.  I'll edit that part out.  As to the `memento` pattern being good for restoring state of an object to its previous states - what do you consider the data in the database if not the *previous state* of the object?

Comment: It could be considered previous state, if all the jobs were, in fact, the same object - just merely recording different states of the same object. But a table would usually store many jobs, that are most likely not the same job. Memento stores mutations of the same object, but it can hardly be applied to store mutations of different objects in this way. Make sense?

Comment: It seems like you're assuming the memento object doesn't have an `Id` property of some kind to relate it to a specific instance's state, in which case you would be correct.  I see no reason to make that assumption, though - in fact, my use case requires exactly the opposite to be true.