# Automapper - How to map a private backing field

Tags: c#, automapper

i'm trying to use Automapper in this scenario. 
I've got an Entity (DDD entity object) that must have private setters for all the properties and collections and i have to map it to a simpler object that will be stored in DB using. 
The Entity have a code like that:

```
    public class TypeA : Entity
{
    private List<TypeB> _assignedItems;
    public IEnumerable<TypeB> AssignedItems
    {
        get { return _assignedItems.ToList(); }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    ...etc...
}`
```

And the Persistence-friendly object

```
[Table("TypeA")]
public class TypeADao : EntityDao
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TypeBDao> AssignedItems { get; set; }
}
```

With Automapper can easily Map the Entity to the Dao, but i fail to do the opposite, as i need to map AssignedItems to the private backing field _assignedItems in the Entity.
How can i do that? 
Is there a way to map the AssignedItems collection to the private field called _assignedItems?
Many thanks to all

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355024/automapper-mapping-properties-with-private-setters

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911950/is-automapper-supposed-to-work-with-private-setters-oob?lq=1

Comment: The first one suggests to use a constructor injection. But i have in the constructor of TypeA the possibility to inject a collection of TypeB, not of TypeBDao, and i cannot create in TypeA an ad-hoc constructor as it would break the ddd rule of making the entity agnostic of persistence (in fact the TypeBDao is a persistence-related object).
The latter states that it successfully map to properties with private setters, but my backing field have a different name (_assignedItems vs AssignedItems) and it will not be mapped

Comment: I have found a workaround by using the constructor and mapping (on the constructor) the TypeBDao to TypeB, but it seems not so clean...any other ideas other than that? =)

Comment: Why not provide private setter for the property, which sets the backing field. Then it will work.

Comment: I'm a dork...thanks for the simple solution =)

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37407912/1360907

Answer (score 5):

I know this might come a bit too late, but should still be helpful for people who might encounter this problem in the future.

Here is how I solved the mapping private field problem.

```
// Please refer to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/600
// Please refer to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/946
ShouldMapField = fieldInfo => !fieldInfo.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
ShouldMapProperty = propertyInfo => true;
```

Comment: I was looking for something very similar, but just mapping everything to backing fields. In which case if anybody reaches this, you should only need:                 ShouldMapField = _ => true;
                ShouldMapProperty = _ => false;